# Flutter - iterate over Object values

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView with all elements.

After tapping on one  I'm redirecting user to DetailPage and then I need to show every value that's not null.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? show every value on what? Detail Page? and how to show? on text field or what?

Comment: I have object that contains of 20+ String values and I need to show them in Text() widget. So i was wondering if there is a way to do it automatically and not to create widget for every value.

Comment: @MateuszFicek Yes, there is a way to do that. If you can share your code (edit your question), we can provide you with a solution.

Comment: ```ListView.builder```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply use this to show if its a null or not

```
// You have some values
var value1, value2, value3;

// You have some widgets
final widget1 = Text('Some Value',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 20)
  );

final widget2 = Text('Some Value',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 20)
  );

final widget3 = Text('Some Value',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 20)
  );

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: new Container(
    child: new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        value1 == null ? widget1 : new Container(),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        value2 == null ? widget2 : new Container(),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        value3 == null ? widget3 : new Container(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```